# Unable to properly configure ASA 5512 with WAN IP

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, wan

I have a /28 block of public IPs from Comcast. I'm trying to put a public IP directly on the ASA outside interface, but when I do I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or the Comcast modem. Internal communication is fine, but there is no external or Internet connectivity.

Also, if I run packet tracer simulating from inside int 172.17.25.1 to outside 8.8.8.8 it says it's blocked by an implicit rule. However, I have even tried opening up both interfaces with any/any in/out and it still says it's blocked. I have also already enabled ICMP inspect.

I can't figure out why traffic is not being passed on the external interface even to a directly connected device.

The Comcast router is in virtual bridge mode.

```
Internet Settings
Gateway MAC Address 78:CD:8E:C2:D2:58
WAN MAC Address 78:CD:8E:C2:D2:5B
WAN DHCP IP Address 98.204.5.208
WAN DHCP IPv6 Address   ::/64
WAN DHCP IPv6 DNS (primary) ::
WAN DHCP IPv6 DNS (secondary)   ::
WAN DHCP Subnet Mask    255.255.248.0
WAN DHCP Default Gateway    98.204.0.1
WAN Internet IP Address 50.xx.xx.62
DNS (primary)   75.75.75.75
DNS (secondary) 75.75.76.76
DHCP Time Remaining 86h:12m:46s
Date    Oct-4-2017
Static IP Block 50.xx.xx.62/28
```

Here is my ASA config

```
ASA Version 9.6(3)1 
!
hostname ciscoasa
enable password lsiIw5sJErKSQdQv encrypted
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd 2KFQnbNIdI.2KYOU encrypted
names

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description Uplink To ComRTR
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 50.xx.xx.50 255.255.255.240 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description Link To 1941
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.17.25.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 management-only
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
boot system disk0:/asa963-1-smp-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object icmp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object icmp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_3
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object icmp
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 any any 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2 any any 
access-list inside_access_out extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_3 any any 
pager lines 24
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-781-150.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
arp rate-limit 8192
nat (any,any) source static any any
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group inside_access_out out interface inside
router ospf 1
 network 172.17.25.0 255.255.255.192 area 0
 area 0
 log-adj-changes
 redistribute static metric 10 metric-type 1 subnets
!
route inside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 50.78.73.62 200
route inside 192.168.108.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.25.2 1
route inside 192.168.118.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.25.2 1
route inside 192.168.128.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.25.2 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
http server enable
http 192.168.128.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 172.17.25.0 255.255.255.192 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 192.168.128.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh 10.2.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh 172.17.25.0 255.255.255.192 inside
ssh timeout 60
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ntp server 129.6.15.30 source outside prefer
ntp server 129.6.15.28 source outside
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect netbios 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly 9
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly 9
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:fc639883d1937e59daa8933d5d290814
: end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never be able to ping from the INSIDE interface IP address of the ASA to any OUTSIDE IP address. The ASA does not allow this.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description Uplink To ComRTR
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 50.78.73.50 255.255.255.240
```

The OUTSIDE interface is connecting to the `50.78.73.48/28` subnet.

The route command is incorrect.

The show run output provided by you states that:

```
route INSIDE 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 50.78.73.62 200
```

The correct OUTPUT will be:

```
route OUTSIDE 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 50.78.73.62
```

!This is where your Internet facing comms are.